# Shell command running with error

Tags: shell, command

When i run the below command i get the output, however it throws

> command not found

error. I have no idea why this error appears. Any suggestions?

```
val1 = ps -ef|grep -i active | wc -l
val2 = 2

echo $val1

if [$val1 -ge $val2]  ; then
        echo "Active MQ process is Running on $HOSTNAME and the process total $(netstat -a | grep 61614 | wc -l)"
else
        echo "Active MQ process appears DOWN $HOSTNAM"
fi
```

Output below,

```
 bash-4.1# ./testact.sh
./testact.sh: line 4: val1: command not found
0
./testact.sh: line 5: val2: command not found

Active MQ process is Running on r00du3n0c and the process total 524
bash-4.1#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your script through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and you'll get this error:

```
Line 6:
if [$val1 -ge $val2]  ; then
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                    ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ].
                    ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Fix that by adding spaces:

```
if [ $val1 -ge $val2 ]  ; then
```

Then you'll get more errors:

```
Line 1:
val1 = ps -ef|grep -i active | wc -l
^-- SC2037: To assign the output of a command, use var=$(cmd) .
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
     ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
              ^-- SC2126: Consider using grep -c instead of grep|wc -l.

Line 2:
val2 = 2
     ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
```

As indicated, remove the spaces and fix the command output assignment.

```
val1=$(ps -ef | grep -i active | wc -l)
val2=2
```

Comment: Even with the spaces, we'd be getting [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) on the new code until quotes are added.